# Scala -- apply unapply rules

Tags: scala, case-class

I'm wondering whether there's a rule or rather a "best practice" in Scala for overridden apply/unapply. I'm in particular interested in whether it's a good idea to have the following property hold:

Given case class C(x: T), for all x, Some(x) == C.unapply(C.apply(x)).

The reason I ask is because of the following code I plan to use to ensure BigDecimal is bounded to a precision of 16.

```
class BoundedBigDecimal(private val bd: BigDecimal) extends Proxy {
  val self: BigDecimal = bd setScale (BoundedBigDecimal.PRECISION)
}

object BoundedBigDecimal {
  val PRECISION = 16
  def apply(bd: BigDecimal) = new BoundedBigDecimal(bd)
  def unapply(bbd: BoundedBigDecimal) = Some(bbd.self)
}
```

As you can see, the property doesn't necessarily hold here.

Is it:

1) A property that should ideally be enforced in the general case?

2) The right way to do what I'm trying to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to use "Tagged type" for that:

```
type Tagged[U] = { type Tag = U }
type @@[T, U] = T with Tagged[U]

trait Bounded

object BoundedBigDecimal {
  val PRECISION = 16

  def apply(bd: BigDecimal) = 
    (bd setScale PRECISION).asInstanceOf[BigDecimal @@ Bounded]

  def unapply(bbd: BigDecimal @@ Bounded) = 
    Some(bbd)

  implicit def toBD(bd: BigDecimal): BigDecimal @@ Bounded = 
    BoundedBigDecimal(bd)
}
```

Good description of Tagged types and benefits of it using is [here](http://etorreborre.blogspot.com/2011/11/practical-uses-for-unboxed-tagged-types.html) and [here](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Tagged+type.html).

Comment: But unlike `newtype`s in Haskell, tagged types in Scala do not prevent you from accidentally adding two different-tagged `BigDecimal`s, as the first post notes.

Answer (score 0):

why not use :

```
def testPrecision(bd:BigDecimal):Boolean = 
db.scale == 16
```

or am i missing something?

edit: update to ReducePrecision:

```
def boundedBD(bd:BigDecimal):BigDecimal =
{   
   val maxPrecision = 16
   bd.scale match {
   case x if x > maxPrecision  => bd setScale  maxPrecision 
   case _ => bd
}


}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Actually, the point isn't to test whether the precision is 16, the point is to force every BigDecimal number to have at most precision 16. That's why I'm defining this BoundedBigDecimal so that BoundedBigDecimal(1.1111111111111111111111111111111111) becomes 1.1111111111111111. Sorry if my question was unclear...